# spring application cannot initialize logging using slf4j-log4j

Tags: java, maven, logging

In my spring application I am trying to use slf4j-log4j logging mechanism but it doesn;t seems to work for me. Neither does it give any error nor does it initialize logging mechanism.

dependencies written in pom.xml are as below...

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${springVersion}</version>
        <exclusions>
         <exclusion>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
         </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- log4j and slf4j -->
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.1</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.14</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>
```

log4j.properties file is as below

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file, stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=[%5p] %d{mm:ss} (%F:%M:%L)%n%m%n%n

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=D:/logs/ov/ov
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %m %n
log4j.appender.file.DatePattern=yyyy-MM-dd-HH'.log'
```

**project runs fine ... but logs aren't getting built. This is what the console shows when I run the project on tomcat**

```
Jun 06, 2014 7:54:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_10\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/bin/client;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/bin;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/lib/i386;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_10\bin;D:\Installations\apache-maven-3.0.4\bin;D:\eclipse;;.
Jun 06, 2014 7:54:08 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:onevalue' did not find a matching property.
Jun 06, 2014 7:54:08 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jun 06, 2014 7:54:08 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jun 06, 2014 7:54:08 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1063 ms
Jun 06, 2014 7:54:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jun 06, 2014 7:54:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.35
Jun 06, 2014 7:54:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles is already defined
Jun 06, 2014 7:54:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Jun 06, 2014 7:54:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Jun 06, 2014 7:54:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'onevalue'
Jun 06, 2014 7:54:27 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jun 06, 2014 7:54:27 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jun 06, 2014 7:54:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 18184 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can see is that you are using a very old version of all of those libraries, and that possibly the provided scope is not appropriate for your configuration. [Maven docs on provided](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html):

> **provided**
>
> This is much like compile, but indicates you expect the JDK or a container to provide the dependency at runtime. For example, when building a web application for the Java Enterprise Edition, you would set the dependency on the Servlet API and related Java EE APIs to scope provided because the web container provides those classes. This scope is only available on the compilation and test classpath, and is not transitive.

Try this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>log4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.14</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hi durron, thanks for the reply. Your answer is correct and I'm doing the same in one of the other projects. But here I cannot make use of the latest slf4j libraries and need to stick with version 1.6.1 of slf4j, also if I'll use the latest version it'll conflict with 1.6.1 placed at a shared path. So I just changed the version of  slf4j in pom.xml. But poof, It stopped working, not even a single exception. And I don't know how to make it work now. Any information?

Comment: And yes... logging doesn't gets initialized when i mark my slf4j v1.6.1 dependencies with <scope>provided</scope>. They work in default case i.e. with no scope tag. Although I have cross-checked that I do have slf4j and slf4j-log4j12 v1.6.1 jars in my classpath.